# Generating random number for class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I have the following code:

```
from numpy import random

class Person():

    def __init__(self, name, age=random.randint(18,65)):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

I want age to be a random number between 18 and 65, unless explicitly specified. However, when I create different instances of this class, like so:

```
p1 = Person('Bob')
p2 = Person('Sue')
p3 = Person('Jeff')
```

Each person always have the same age. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for that behaviour is that default value for attributes is being initialised and set just once, so code snippet `random.randint(18,65)` would be executed and set as default value for age, that is the reason for having same default value for age if age not provided.

**To fix problem** set the default value to None and perform check and assign of random value if needed:

```
from numpy import random


class Person():

    def __init__(self, name, age=None):
        if age is None:
            age = random.randint(18,65)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Useful info regarding default attributes:

- [Mutable Default Arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)
- [Default parameters values](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNg-ue18fWAhVqxFQKHWjgAckQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Feffbot.org%2Fzone%2Fdefault-values.htm&usg=AFQjCNHTF-1MA80yeTwzCC-EOqvrctyFLA)

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `age` is always the same is because the value for your `age` parameter is defined when the method `__init__` is defined and it wont be recreated every time you call your method, move the instantiation of the variable `age` inside the method if you want this to change every time the method is called

```
from numpy import random

class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age if age else random.randint(18, 65)

p1 = Person('Bob')
p2 = Person('Sue', 20)
p3 = Person('Jeff')

print(p1.age)
>> 56
print(p2.age)
>> 20
print(p3.age)
>> 20

print(Person('Sue', 20).age)
>> 20
```

Comment: What is the age value for Person('Sue', 0)  ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko It's 20, your answer is an exact copy of this answer, how is it 0?

Comment: yes it's super similar,but not same, the `if age` vs `if age is None` is completely different, also explaining reasoning is the different from my point of view (that's the reasoning for giving another answer if you are interested in the reason).

Comment: I am interested in the difference? One tests if a value is a NoneType and the other checks if the values is not = 0? Is that correct?

Comment: nope, one check for NoneType another check whether value is falsy(more there: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)

Comment: Theoretically we may need to create instance of Person with age 0 and increment age after birth, also it's not always clear whether intial person age is 1 or 0, depends on agreed rules.